# Inductor with no resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Lets think about inductor that has no resistance. In initial condition, current is $I$, and the mag field is created only by inductor's current. And suppose that there is no battery connected. Now here is my question.

1. Does mag flux of inductor is always $LI$? ($L$ is inductance of the inductor)
2. If it doesn't, what happens to mag flux?

Comment: Please make a statement about the complete circuit which contains the inductor otherwise it is difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the circuit is closed and only consists of the inductor, then the magnetic flux ($LI$) will be conserved and current will $I$ will continue flowing forever.

This case is similar to a L-R circuit with the resistance $R\rightarrow 0$. So the time constant of the circuit,
$$ \tau =\frac{L}{R} \: \: \text {when} \:\: R \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{R\to 0}\tau = \infty  $$

So clearly, the time constant ($\tau$) comes out to be $\infty$, which means that the current in the circuit will decay by a factor of $e$ (current becomes $\approx 36.7\%$) after time intervals of $\infty$, which is a fancy way of saying that the current will remain constant.